# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty }\int_0^1 f(x)g_n(x)d\mu(x)=0.$

Tags: measure-theory

> Consider $g_n:\mathbb R\to\{-1,1\}$ define for all $n$ by 
>   $$g_n(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor nx\rfloor},$$
>   show that for all $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ mesurable and bounded,
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\int_0^1 f(x)g_n(x)d\mu(x)=0.$$

In the correction, they firstly consider $f=\chi_I$ (the characteristic function of $I$) where $I\subset [0,1]$ is an interval. I don't undertand why
$$\left|\int_{[0,1]}f(x)g_n(x)d\mu(x)\right|\leq\frac{1}{n}.$$

**Notation:** $\mu$ reprensent the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found. So if somebody is interested:

For $n$ fixed and $x\in[0,1]$, 
$$\lfloor nx\rfloor=k\ \ \text{ if }x\in\left[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}\right[, k=0,...,n-1$$
and thus

\begin{align*}
\left|\int_0^1 f(x)g_n(x)\mu(dx)\right|&=\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k+1}{n}}\chi_I(x)(-1)^k\mu(dx)\right|\\
&\underset{\chi_I\ \leq\ \chi_{[0,1]}}{\leq}\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k+1}{n}}(-1)^k\mu(dx)\right|\\
&= \left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\int_{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k+1}{n}}\mu(dx)\right|\\
&= \left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\underbrace{\mu\left(\left[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}\right]\right)}_{=\mu\left(\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]\right)}\right|\\
&=\mu\left(\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]\right) \underbrace{\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k\right|}_{=0\text{ or }1}\\
&\leq\mu\left(\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$(-1)^{\lfloor nx\rfloor}$ is a $\frac{1}{n}$-periodic function, hence the absolute value of the last integral cannot exceed the absolute value of the same integral over a period.

Comment: I actualy already answers to my proper question (I found the thing), can you just check the end of my proof ?

Comment: @idm: it looks fine to me.

Comment: So you agree with $\mu([0,1/n])=\frac{1}{n}$ ? why ?

Comment: @idm: If $\mu$ is the standard Lebesgue measure, it is trivial, $\mu([a,b])=b-a$ by definition.

Comment: of course, but it's not the Lebesgue measure. We always denote the Lebesgue mesure by $m$ and not $\mu$.

Comment: @idm: in that case, I agree that $\frac{1}{n}$ should be replaced by $\mu\left([0,\frac{1}{n}]\right)$.